# In c++, how do you get the input of a string, float and integer from 1 line?

Tags: c++

An input file is entered with the following data:

```
Juan Dela Cruz 150.50 5
```

'Juan Dela Cruz' is a name that I would like to assign to string A,
'150.50' is a number I would like to assign to float B
and 5 is a number I would like to assign to int C.

If I try `cin`, it is delimited by the spaces in between.
If I use `getline`, it's getting the whole line as a string.

What would be the correct syntax for this?

Comment: how do you know where the end of the name is?

Comment: Read the whole string as a single line. Then *analyze* the string to work out where the breaks are between A, B and C. Then convert each part to the type you require. There's no quick way to do this. It could easily be 10 lines of code (depending on exactly how you do it).

Comment: Answer to yourself the question asked by Alan. Then always read the whole line and apply the rule you came up with. Use search functions (e.g. from the back) to do so.

Comment: @john Are you going to make an answer? Or refer to a dupe? If neither please allow me to answer using your comment in combination with mine.

Comment: @Yunnosch Go ahead, make an answer.

Comment: Just to state the obvious: it is *very* bad practice to use column separators within your fields.

Comment: @dejoma You, like more than one of the answerers below, seem to think that OP is in control of the format of the input, or responsible for it. What gives you that impression?

Comment: I don't have control of the format of the input. This was a given: Juan Dela Cruz 150.50 5 and there are actually more lines to it with the same format. I like the idea of breaking down the string from the end. The fields are in this order: STRING (may have 1 or more spaces between the words) FLOAT INT. If we look at it from the end, we can get the INT from the end, use the space as delimiter, then get the next as FLOAT, then use the space again, then get everything else as a STRING. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we analyze the string, then we can make the following observation. At the very end, we have an integer. In front of the integer we have a space. And in front of that the float value. And again in fron of that a space.

So, we can simply look from the back of the string for the 2nd last space. This can easily be achieved by

```
size_t position = lineFromeFile.rfind(' ', lineFromeFile.rfind(' ')-1);
```

We need a nested statement of `rfind` please see [here, version no 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind).

Then we build a substring with the name. From start of the string up to the found position.

For the numbers, we put the rest of the original string into an `std::istringstream` and then simply extract from there.

Please see the following simple code, which has just a few lines of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <sstream>

int main() {

    // This is the string that we read via getline or whatever
    std::string lineFromeFile("Juan Dela Cruz 150.50 5");

    // Let's search for the 2nd last space
    size_t position = lineFromeFile.rfind(' ', lineFromeFile.rfind(' ')-1);

    // Get the name as a substring from the original string
    std::string name = lineFromeFile.substr(0, position);

    // Put the numbers in a istringstream for better extraction
    std::istringstream iss(lineFromeFile.substr(position));

    // Get the rest of the values
    float fValue;
    int iValue;
    iss >> fValue >> iValue;

    // Show result to use
    std::cout << "\nName:\t" << name << "\nFloat:\t" << fValue << "\nInt:\t" << iValue << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and I was able to extract the last 2 values - fValue and iValue. How do I extract 'Juan Dela Cruz'? I'm assuming I can get the first 2 values, and just get what ever is remaining? How do I do that?

Comment: Yes, correct. We take, whatever is before the 2nd last space. And for that we use the substr-function. This will take as parameter the start position (0, so from the beginning of the string) and as "number of characters", the calculated position of 2nd last space. The code in the answer does exactly that. So, the answer is: use substr

Answer (score 1):

Probably simplest in this case would be to read whole line into string and then parse it with regex:

```
const std::regex reg("\\s*(\\S.*)\\s+(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)\\s+(\\d+)\\s*");

std::smatch match;
if (std::regex_match( input, match, reg)) {
    auto A = match[1];
    auto B = std::stof( match[2] );
    auto C = std::stoi( match[4] );
} else {
     // error invalid format
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/gK2zR1)

Answer (score 0):

As always when the input does not (or sometimes does not) match a strict enough syntax,  read the whole line and then apply the rules which to a human are "obvious".

In this case (quoting comment by john):

> Read the whole string as a single line. Then analyze the string to work out where the breaks are between A, B and C. Then convert each part to the type you require.

Specifically, you probably want to use reverse searching functions (e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strrchr ), because the last parts of the input seem the most strictly formatted, i.e. easiest to parse. The rest is then the unpredictable part at the start.

Answer (score -1):

use the same symbol after each data package, for example, Juan Dela Cruz;150.50;5 then you can check for a ; and separate your string there.
If you want to use the same input format you could use digits as an indicator to separate them

Comment: I do not think that chaging the input format is an option.

Comment: Yunnosch is correct. I can't change the format at this point.

Answer (score -1):

either try inputting the different data type in different lines and then use line breaks to input different data types or use the distinction to differentiate different data types like adding a . or comma

Comment: I do not think that chaging the input format is an option.